# Работа с файлами на клиентской стороне

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net, файлы, веб-служба

Добрый день! Возможно ли копировать/перемещать файлы на клиентской стороне, используя asp.net. Естественно, с полученного разрешения пользователя. Подойдут любые идеи на этот счёт. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Так нельзя. Это защита определяется браузером.

Можно поставить клиенту сервис(приложение) на его машину, но задачи по работе с файлами этот сервис будет получать с сервера.

PS: написание злобных ActiveX компонентов я не рассматриваю...

Comment: А давать команды этому сервису через сайт также не представляется возможным?

Comment: @loqie ну как раз сервис и будет получать команды с сайта...

Comment: А не подскажете какую связку лучше использовать с asp.net mvc. WCF подойдёт для этих целей или лучше что-то другое использовать? я так понимаю сервис будет висеть у клиента в службе и не беспокоить?

Comment: @loqie 1. в каждом конкретном случае свой подход "лучше". ASP.NET WebApi хорошая штука... Есть фанаты WCF... Ну, выбирайте на вкус и от задачи... 2. Да, как сервис или можно сделать winforms приложение спрятать его в трей...